# Tradução Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

Fiz uma busca e encontrei apenas uma tradução para o PT-PT (Português - Portugal), existe algum projeto ou pacote para tradução de erros e afins ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesse repositório do GitHub temos no total 37 traduções para as mensagens do Laravel 4, incluindo PT-BR.

https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel4-lang

Basta dar um `git clone` e copiar para diretório para a sua aplicação.