# Como faço pra traduzir para pt-BR?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

tenho um formulário com seguinte código:

```
{{ Form::selectMonth('month') }}
```

isso me retorna os meses em inglês, como faço para traduzir o retorne dele para português?

Comment: Eu nunca usei Laravel, mas talvez isto funcione: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37911/3635

Comment: eu tenho esse.... essas traduções são para msg do sistema... não resolve aqui não... mas vlw pela atenção

Comment: Já pensou em fazer um `<select>` manualmente, usando um array por exemplo?

Comment: Tente usar `App::setLocale('pt')`. Algumas informações [aqui](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/localization).

Answer (score -2):

> Tente fazer manualmente:

```
{{ Form::selectMonth('month') }}
```

*Produza as suas opções:*

```
<select name="month">
  <option value="1">Janeiro</option>
  <option value="2">fevereiro</option>
...
</select>
```

**Outro exemplo:**

```
{{ Form::selectMonth('month', 7, ['class' => 'field']) }}

<select class="field" name="month">
  <option value="1">Janeiro</option>
  <option value="2">fevereiro</option>
  <option value="3">Março</option>
  <option value="4">Abril</option>
  <option value="5">Maio</option>
  <option value="6">Junho</option>
  <option value="7" selected="selected">Julho</option>

</select>
```

[Fonte](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/166/creating-a-month-selection-field)

Comment: não sei onde faço o select do meu jeito e chamo com {{ Form::selectMonth('month') }}

Answer (score -3):

Para deixar todo o yii2 em pt-BR português Brasil

edite o arquivo `config/web.php` e acrescenta as linhas dentro de `$config:`

```
$config = [
    'language' => 'pt-BR',
    'sourceLanguage'=>'pt-BR',
    ...
]
```